# How to sort list with order by case when clause (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I am trying to sort a list based on `month` and `id`, such that if it's a certain `month` and `id` it will be sorted at the top, otherwise sort below.

I was hoping to use an order by with case when clause, but am getting the following error:

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

**Query**

```
declare @month int = month(getDate())

select distinct 
[description],
[item],
[meta]
order by case
when @month = 1 and item = 'A00' then 12
when @month = 2 and item = 'B00' then 11
when @month = 3 and item = 'C00' then 10
when @month = 4 and item = 'D00' then 9
when @month = 5 and item = 'E00' then 8
when @month = 6 and item = 'F00' then 7
when @month = 7 and item = 'G00' then 6
when @month = 8 and item = 'H00' then 5
when @month = 9 and item = 'I00' then 4
when @month = 10 and item = 'J00' then 3
when @month = 11 and item = 'K00' then 2
when @month = 12 and item = 'L00' then 1
else 0 end desc
```

How can I rank these on two arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace DISTICNT to GROUP BY.